# VB.net and Webservices Exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, visual-studio, encoding

I am calling a webservice through VB.NET. I have done a AddWebReference to create the bindings.

When a WS call throws an exception, I am able to catch it as a generic Exception object  `Catch ex As Exception`.
However, I am not able to figure out how to catch it as the Exception Type Actually thrown.

From my wsdl

```
<wsdl:message name="FException">
    <wsdl:part name="fault" type="tns2:FException"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="MyException">
    <wsdl:part name="fault" type="impl:MyException"/>
</wsdl:message>

<complexType name="FException">
    <sequence>
        <element name="errcode" type="xsd:int"/>
        <element name="errmessage" nillable="true" type="soapenc:string"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>


<complexType name="MyException">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns2:FException"><sequence/>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

The actual Exception thrown is MyException. However, the AddWebreference doesn't seem to create any class named MyException, so using

```
 Catch ex As MyException
```

gives me

```
Type 'MyException' is not defined.
```

I am able to catch the right exception in Java with Axis.

What am I missing here in VB.NET? The Add WebReference doesn't seem to generate the Exception objects so I cannot use them.

Comment: Have you tried using the full Namespace? MyService.MyException for example

Comment: @James - yes same error.

Comment: If you use object explorer on the service, can you see the MyException type in there?

Comment: @James - Nope, I don't see it.

Comment: If it isn't there, you cant use it. Possibly something is up with the service reference or the service itself? I can't tell from the WSDL.

Comment: @James - I can use the same thing in Java.

Comment: I'm not a java dev, can you see the exception type in the java equivalent to object explorer?

Comment: @James - yes in Java, Axis generates all the exception classes from the same WSDL. So my question here is why doesn't VB.net

Comment: The WSDL / Service has not changed between getting used in java and .NET? very weird indeed. Recreate the service reference in case it's a weird anomaly? (getting short on ideas).

Comment: No change in the WSDL. And recreated the webreference multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer to this.

The webservice was a rather old implementation which used "RPC/Encoded" instead of the more current encodings like "Document/Literal" or "RPC/Literal". The dotnet stub generators don't support RPC/Encoded. Hence the issue.